# No Directive annotation found on HttpService

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I am writing an angular 2 component to test out Http services and I have this:

Here is my app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HttpService} from './http.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <div class="input">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" #title>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <label for="body">Body</label>
                <input type="text" id="body" #body>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <label for="user-id">User ID</label>
                <input type="text" id="user-id" #userId>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <button (click)="onPost(title.value, body.value, userId.value)">Post Data</button>
            <button (click)="onGetPosts()">Get All Posts</button>
            <p>Response: {{response | json}}</p>
        </div>
    `,
    directives: [HttpService]
})
export class AppComponent {
    response: string;
    constructor(private _httpService: HttpService) {};
    onGetPosts() {
        this._httpService.getPosts()
            .subscribe(
                response => this.response = response,
                error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
}
```

I believe my error is within this file.  When I compiled the code I got the error 
[image: EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on HttpService]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I was including the HttpService as a directive in my component decorator when I should have been including it as a provider in providers

```
        <button (click)="onGetPosts()">Get All Posts</button>
        <p>Response: {{response | json}}</p>
    </div>
`,
providers: [HttpService]
})
export class AppComponent {
    response: string;
    constructor(private _httpService: HttpService) {};
    onGetPosts() {
```